# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':enx_flutter_plugin:compileDebugAidl'

Tags: flutter-dependencies

how to use the  enx_flutter_plugin: ^1.8.0 plugin .
When in run the app it showing me the error-

Could not determine the dependencies of task ':enx_flutter_plugin:compileDebugAidl'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':enx_flutter_plugin:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find :Enx-Rtc-Android-Release_1.9.6:.
> Required by:
> project :enx_flutter_plugin

Please help me in that.

my gradle version is - classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
flutter version is - Flutter 1.22.4 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 1aafb3a8b9 (8 months ago) • 2020-11-13 09:59:28 -0800
Engine • revision 2c956a31c0
Tools • Dart 2.10.4

i tried all the possibilites --
like , Change the dart version, Changer the flutter version, change the plugin version, lear the cache, Flutter clean.

Please help me am stuck here